# Как в тестах mocha протестировать успешное выполнение функции?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha

Есть функция:

```
fc() {
  fc1();
  fc2();
  ...
}
```

Какой метод у assert есть, просто убедиться, что функция выполнилась без ошибок?

```
assert.<метод>(fc());
```

Answer (score 0):

Да в общем-то можно просто вызвать функцию. Если она кидает исключение, то тест не пройдёт.
Если хочется именно с `assert`, то есть метод [`assert.doesNotThrow`](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert_doesnotthrow_fn_error_message), хотя там прямо написано «Using assert.doesNotThrow() is **actually not useful** [...]»

```
assert.doesNotThrow(fc);
```

Обратите внимание, что `assert` сам вызовет функцию поэтому скобочек у `fc` нет.

Comment: а если fc не кидает исключения?
будет ли ловить обычные ошибка типа: "cannot read property of undefined"...

Comment: Это тоже исключения